# Dynamically allocated array of arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a problem with array of arrays object. I tried the default Java array like this:

```
String[][] array = new String[5][5];
```

And it worked. But now I'm facing for another problem. I don't know the sizes of the array so I need a dynamically allocated array of arrays. I tried this:

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arrayOfArrays = new ArrayList<>();

array.add("1");
array.add("2");
array.add("3");
arrayOfArrays.add(array);
System.out.println(arrayOfArrays);
array.clear();
array.add("4");
array.add("5");
array.add("6");
arrayOfArrays.add(array);
System.out.println(arrayOfArrays);
```

And it prints:

```
[[1, 2, 3]]
[[4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6]]
```

And I don't need to rewrite it. It should looks like this:

```
[[1, 2, 3]]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

I'm facing for this problem very long time and I tried a lot of workarounds but I need some clever solution. Also I will appreciate any help.

And I have a second question. How to add it in cycle? Because it has the same output as in the first case.
For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.size() - 1; i++) {
    arrayOfArrays.add(swap(array, i, i+1));       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are adding the same `ArrayList` instance twice to the outer `List`.

You need to create two distinct `ArrayList` instances to add to your `arrayOfArrays`.

Replace

```
array.clear();
```

with

```
array = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be aware that you're  just using the same `array` object, and add it to the `arrayOfArrays` twice, that why it prints out the same thing twice.

What you need is actually this:

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arrayOfArrays = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<String> array1 = new ArrayList<>();
    array1.add("1");
    array1.add("2");
    array1.add("3");
    arrayOfArrays.add(array1);
    System.out.println(arrayOfArrays);

    ArrayList<String> array2= new ArrayList<>();
    array2.add("4");
    array2.add("5");
    array2.add("6");
    arrayOfArrays.add(array2);
    System.out.println(arrayOfArrays);
```